# Access struct reference after passing it to a vector

Tags: rust

I am trying to pass a set of structs which are implementations of a given trait to a vector.  This vector is passed around and the contents iterated and interacted with.  Everything is working in practice but when it comes to testing, I want to keep hold of the vector item, create the list and then assert on the item following processing.

I have created an example, I cannot get the final test to pass and have tried numerous different signatures of the struct, the trait implementation and the mutability definitions.

Here is the example implementation with the last test failing.

```rust
trait Abstract {
    fn do_something(&mut self) -> i32;
    fn get_value(&self) -> i32;
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct ConcreteA {
    value: String,
}

impl Abstract for ConcreteA {
    fn do_something(&mut self) -> i32 {
        self.value = String::from("Boom Boom");
        return self.value.len() as i32;
    }

    fn get_value(&self) -> i32 {
        return self.value.len() as i32;
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_something() {
    let mut s = ConcreteA::default();
    s.do_something();
    assert_eq!(9, s.get_value());
}

#[test]
fn test_passing_to_vector() {
    let s = ConcreteA::default();
    let mut list = vec![s];
    for item in list.iter_mut().map(|e| e as &mut dyn Abstract) {
        item.do_something();
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_passing_to_vector_typed_to_trait() {
    let s = ConcreteA::default();
    let mut list: Vec<Box<dyn Abstract>> = vec![Box::new(s)];
    for item in list.iter_mut() {
        item.do_something();
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_accessing_concrete_after_processing() {
    let s = ConcreteA::default();
    let mut list: Vec<Box<dyn Abstract>> = vec![Box::new(s)];
    for item in list.iter_mut() {
        item.do_something();
    }
    assert_eq!(9, s.get_value());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f9f037cf335b5038c8385b6ecb165283)

Comment: [Simplified repro](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=432e21765c1c4ec5144322fe17fa2cea). The Box and the trait are distractions -- the problem is that you've moved the struct into the Vec. If you mutate the struct, that changes bytes inside the Vec's internal storage. If you keep a local copy of the struct (which you could choose to do), that won't be the same as the copy inside the Vec which your call do `do_something` mutates. Equally you can't reference the struct stored inside the Vec, as that might move around in memory as the Vec resizes

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1ced5d80193c3256ac0b8ac96fd15017). You may also want to look at the `Any` trait to allow downcasting from the trait object to a concrete type, or just reference the value in the vector (`list.last().unwrap().get_value()`)